# Can't login to my localhost phpMyAdmin page

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm new to PHP, MySQL, and apache, just "installed" apache localhost server, MySQL, MySQL workbench, PHP, and PHPMyAdmin to my mac.
I followed all the instructions to install those and command lines on terminal, everything works except for the PHPMyAdmin. When I put my username which is root and the password that I set up on phpmyadmin/setup, it shows two errors.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmnoA.png)

**First error:** `mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]`

**Second error:** `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

I started all over again several times but I can't access to phpMyAdmin page. Please help!

Comment: I have a Mac, and this method worked for me!

1) Open MySQL pannel
2) Click Initialize Database
3) Set the password and click "Use Legacy Password Encryption"
4) Start the Server again
This solved all my problems with above two errors and 'sudo mysql command not found' on terminal.